# Can I actually turn this kid invisible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Solitude, there is a kid named Kayd who runs around playing tag with his friends and occasionally taunting me. If I cast any spell in front of him, he approaches me to ask if I can make him invisible, and I can convince him that he is. But however much fun it is watching him running around thinking he's invisible, it would be much more fun to see him running around *actually* invisible.

I don't have a Thief character advanced enough to reverse-pickpocket him with an invisibility potion, but if I did, would he use it?

Comment: "it would be much more fun to see him running around actually invisible."
How do you see someone who is invisible?

Comment: @onewho Using Detect Life of course!

Comment: In response to your update (glad the spell worked!) if Kayd **thinks** he's invisible after the conversation then surely you just cast the spell and you actually have the desired effect - an invisible kid, running around thinking he's invisible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No.**

In the base game there is only one spell that induces invisibility and that is targeted only at the caster. Since children cannot learn spells, nor can they be pick-pocketed (reverse or otherwise), there's no way to do this in the game.

*However*, if you are on PC then you can use the console to acquire the [Fade Other](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fade_Other) spell which isn't available anywhere in the game. Fade Other, as the name suggests, allows you to target an NPC with the spell and they become invisible for 30 seconds. The ID for Fade Other is `00028532` so you can use the console command `player.addspell 00028532` (you can omit the leading zeros) to add it to your spell book.

Here's a reference explaining the limitations of children in the game: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Children

---

**Update:**

If you're playing the Special Edition on PS4 or Xbox One you could just create a mod which adds this spell into the game somewhere and deploy the mod to [Bethesda.net](https://bethesda.net). I'm unsure if a mod that does this has already been created.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I gave myself the Fade Other spell and wandered Skyrim testing it. Most NPCs react with special dialogue when Fade Other is cast on them, but only if they are currently your follower. Kharjo, for instance, remarks, "I could be a great hunter like this." NPCs not following you, unfortunately including Kayd, do not react at all under normal circumstances. I haven't tried again on a fresh save to see if I get a special option in Kayd's "turn me invisible" dialogue menu for knowing Fade Other. (moved to a comment b/c a mod removed this from my answer)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could mix a poison with invisibility as an additional effect and slap it on that [fork](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fork_(weapon)#Fork) you can find in Riften that only does one point of damage as a weapon.  Additionally, there's a [5% chance](http://cs.uesp.net/index.php?game=sr&script=DA15WabbajackEffectSCRIPT) that Wabbajack will trigger the invisibility effect.